# django-datatable default iDisplayLength

Tags: jquery, python, django, datatable

I am using https://github.com/shymonk/django-datatable for a table.

By default, it would display only 10 records, and there is a Length Menu to choose a different number.

I see in the Ajax call that it asks for `iDisplayLength=10` on first load.

How can I overwrite it to display 100 at first?

I read through the source code and the documentation, but I am newbie to django and not sure how to overwrite it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can see from their source code: [class TableOptions](https://github.com/shymonk/django-datatable/blob/master/table/tables.py#L130) which is used for [meta options](https://github.com/shymonk/django-datatable/blob/master/table/tables.py#L201) and can be accessed for the same to set different properties.

So as I see it, adding a `Meta` can help you, like this:

```
class AjaxTable(Table):
    id = Column(field='id', header=u'#')
    name = Column(field='name', header=u'NAME')
    organization = Column(field='organization.name', header=u'ORG')

    class Meta:
        model = Person
        ajax = True
        page_length = 100  # Add this and see
```

The `page_length` is the set of options that I could see inside the [`TableOptions`](https://github.com/shymonk/django-datatable/blob/master/table/tables.py#L180)

Comment: Thanks! now sure how I missed it. I will document it